# Elements are not properly contained in card-footer in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have created a form that is contained in a [Bootstrap 4 Card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/) as follows:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row card">
        <div class="col-12 card-body">
            Example text in the card body
        </div>

        <div class="col-12 card-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="alert alert-warning col-12">Example alert box</div>
            </div>

            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Save form</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The usual content goes in the `div.card-body`, I placed an alert box as well as my "Save form" button in the `div.card-footer`.

This works in Chrome 63 and Firefox 58. However in Internet Explorer 11 the save button and alert are not properly contained within the card footer, they overflow the `div` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9ksl.png)).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue can be resolved by removing the `col-12` class, which I used in combination with `card-footer`:

```
<div class="col-12 card-footer">
```

becomes

```
<div class="card-footer">
```

Bootstrap's `col-12` class adds this CSS

```
-ms-flex: 0 0 100%; 
flex: 0 0 100%;
```

to the `div`. Toggling these CSS definitions, or replacing the 3rd argument (`flex-basis`) `100%` with `auto` or a fixed value, seem to fix this this particular issue as well, although I'm not sure why and what the side-effects might be.

Comment: I'm guessing the Self-Learner badge is waiting for you. I'm gonna get you started on the way there! :-)

Comment: If the `content-box` is used, the `padding` should _add_ to the height, which it clearly doesn't. Instead it collapse to the size of the `padding`, so why does it do that?

Comment: Furthermore, if you change from 100% to 200px, it works just fine, so why is that, if a _non-auto_ `flex-basis` is the reason?

Comment: @WebDevBooster This is not a correct answer, removing 100% works, though the reason why has nothing to do with `content-box` (unless you can answer/explain my two above comment's questions)

Comment: @LGSon I knew you'd chime in after the `flexbox` tag was added. Thanks for letting me know. I certainly still have quite a few ways to go as far as flexbox is concerned. :-)

Comment: @LGSon Thank you for the comments. I think I misunderstood some things about the explanation and effects of Flexbug#7 in my reasoning, I reworded/removed that section.